# Any possible way to rasterize views in Android, just like in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, android-recyclerview, rasterize

In iOS I can do a call like

```
self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

Is there anything similar in Android in terms of rasterizing views and therefore not getting `onDraw()` being called consistently?

I would like to prevent views from being drawn over and over again in a `RecyclerView` to save memory and optimized for faster scrolling.

Comment: I don't understand how this has anything to do with this question and I didn't spot any glaring grammar issues?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but did you manage to figure this out?